# Is there any easier way to write a scrollTop animation?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm wondering if there is an easier or better way of writing a JQuery animation which triggers after a certain point.

The code that I have at the moment looks like;

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
        <div id="box"></div>
    </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();

        if(scrolled > 300) {
            $("#box").css("margin-left", "300px");
        } else {
            $("#box").css("margin-left", "0px");       
        }
    });
```

Also is there away to add different amount of time each animation will take to complete instead of add a `.css("transition", "all 2s");`

Comment: can you describe a bit more what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @alpha sorry i just want to know Is there a better way to write the script?

Comment: if you are implying for writing animate I would use $("#box").animate({left: '300px'}, 2000);

Comment: @alpha ok cool now i have control over the speed, however now it doesn't return with-in the else statement, any ideas?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ub30gzp4/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast Doesn't that seem like more code, but i guess it can be applied to multiple divs now

Comment: No, you really want to leave CSS to do it's job, there is really no point in forcing jQuery to instantiate some CSS transitions. Unless you were using some GPU optimized JavaScript library then jQuery will probably run slower/lag your page more than a normal CSS transition would.

Comment: why would you need else statement ?

Comment: @alpha I have it working I was just wondering of other ways of doing it or even better ways. Its just Im new to JQuery and want to know different ways of doing things.

Comment: with animation we have different ways to implement tasks

Comment: @alpha to make it return when below 300px

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no just want to learn Jquery and wondering what the best way to animate would be

Comment: Thank you guys for the different ways of doing this, hopefully I will be able to make cool things happen but expect more questions on SO from me :)

Comment: @alpha thats really cool but can you explain it a little or comment the jQuery as I'm confused :) i understand that on hover animate top. But i don't get how it comes back or easeOutBounce

Comment: I thought you had found your answer and deleted my post since it is getting really long in here. http://jsfiddle.net/Durdona/u1xe9Laq/   here it is if you need it ... I can't go in chat it would be easier for me

Comment: @alpha I don't think i removed your post, i tired to move it to chat but it says failed for some reason, I would just like a little explanation on how your code works incase i need it in the future, Im making a file will lots of different jQuery animations and set scroll speed. so this would be create addition

Comment: I have the same error can't be forwarded into chat :(  Actually I came up with this hover animation recently ... It has two callback function mouseenter and mouseleave with animation inside

Comment: @alpha its cool but I have no clue how it works :)

Comment: We can't have long discussion here ... this is another example in 3D http://jsfiddle.net/Durdona/67aL3jp6/1/ ... I wish I had access to chat so I could explain

Comment: @alpha Thank You for the cool animation I have added them to my file, hopefully they will come in handy! Thanks once again and its a shame the chat is working ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR : Yes, there are multiple ways to fire off transitions from jQuery, JavaScript, and CSS.

There are a few ways and I have showcased them in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub30gzp4/1/), you can comment/uncomment my code as necessary to see two different ways of using transitions.

### 1st Option

jQuery

```
$('#box').addClass("margin-left-300");
```

CSS:

```
 transition: 2s all ease;
```

Which, when combined with the ability of removing a class, it will allow the CSS to operate with as little interference as possible from jQuery.

### 2nd Option

jQuery:

```
$('#box').animate({marginLeft: "300px"}, 1000)
```

This will allow for the jQuery to act upon the transition when necessary and specify what should happen in the transition, and how long the transition should last.

**What's Better?**

Honestly, I'm currently working on a pretty big SPA (single page application) that requires a lot of transitions and movements. I made the silly mistake of attempting to use only jQuery for my animations, which proved to be unreliable and choppy at times.

The following is an article that explains the difference between CSS and Javascript:

[CSS Animations vs JQuery Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094587/css-animations-vs-jquery-animations)

In my opinion, I think it would be best to limit the amount of jQuery interference with CSS transitions as soon/much as possible unless you plan on using a JavaScript library that will outperform the native CSS.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depthness i has helped a lot!! I will be sure to try and keep my jQuery to as little as possible!