# mouseover and mouseout functions under div

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if there was any way to use the .mouseover and .mouseout jQuery events "through" a div. What I mean is, I have an image placed inside a div, with another div over it. The div over the image is used to tint the image. Because of this opaque layer, the events do not function. However, when I remove the opaque layer, the events work as intended. Here is a copy of my HTML:

```
    <div id="commercialopacity"></div>
    <p class="commercial">COMMERCIAL</p>
    <div id="hideimage"></div>
    <div class="portfolioimages">
        <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioimages">
        <img class="picture" id="commercialimage2" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg" link="index.html">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolioimages">
        <img class="picture" id="commercialimage3" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="residential"></div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$("#commercialimage1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#commercialimage1").animate({marginLeft:"20%"},{duration:250, queue:false});
})
$("#commercialimage1").mouseout(function(){
    $("#commercialimage1").animate({marginLeft:"0%"},{duration:250,queue:false});
})
$("#commercialimage2").mouseover(function(){
    $("#commercialimage2").animate({marginLeft:"20%"},{duration:250, queue:false});
})
$("#commercialimage2").mouseout(function(){
    $("#commercialimage2").animate({marginLeft:"0%"},{duration:250, queue:false});
})
$("#commercialimage3").mouseover(function(){
    $("#commercialimage3").animate({marginLeft:"20%"},{duration:250,queue:false});
})
$("#commercialimage3").mouseout(function(){
    $("#commercialimage3").animate({marginLeft:"0%"},{duration:250,queue:false});
})
```

So, #commercialopacity is the div that tints the images above.
Also, is there any way I can condense my jQuery code for this animation? I realize that this probably is not the cleanest way to do this, especially if I want to use these events for other images that I add in the future.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: _"Also, is there any way I can condense my jQuery code for this animation?"_ - first and foremost you want to make the acquaintance of a certain `$(this)` ... And for the animation parameters, you might want to look into custom data attributes, so that you can place them directly _on_ the image elements in the HTML code, and read them from there.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
https://jsfiddle.net/xcm02m4b/1/

CSS:

```
#container{
  max-width: 200px;
}
#commercialopacity{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  transition: background-color .25s;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
#container:hover #commercialopacity{
  background-color:transparent;
}
.picture{
  position: relative;
  transition: margin-left .25s;
}
#commercialimage1{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#commercialimage2{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#commercialimage3{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.picture:hover{
  margin-left: 20%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="commercialopacity"></div>
<p class="commercial">COMMERCIAL</p>
<div id="hideimage"></div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage2" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg" link="index.html">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
    <img class="picture" id="commercialimage3" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div id="residential"></div>
```

I switched your animate js to css animations. Much faster if there isn't too many objects and simple enough for what you're going for

Comment: Would you consider css animations superior to pure JS or jQuery? Also, the jfiddle that you linked has the div disappearing. I want the opaque layer to remain, because, essentially, when the image moves over, I want there to be a text box describing the image, but I want the box to have the same green tint.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

you can just remove the background setting from the #container:hover and the background will stay.

I use CSS for simple effects like hover for color changes and small movements on buttons/images. Anything more complex, I'd use some library that offer customizeable animations like you have with .animate()
I think pure JS would always have a slight performance advantage over jQuery since jQuery is built on top of js.

Comment: also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094587/css-animations-vs-jquery-animations

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally agree with Liquidchrome. A pure css solution is the best option here. I've made a snippet wich probably solves your problem.

```css
#container {
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, .5);
}

.picture {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: no-repeat 100%/auto 100%;
  transition: padding-left .3s;
}

.picture::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 100, 0, .5);
}

.picture:hover {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="commercial">COMMERCIAL</p>
  <div id="hideimage"></div>
  <a class="picture" id="commercialimage1" style="background-image:url(https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/9034/2568020-4372935613-any%252.jpg)" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466639"></a>
  <a class="picture" id="commercialimage2" style="background-image:url(https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/9034/2568020-4372935613-any%252.jpg)" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466639"></a>
  <a class="picture" id="commercialimage3" style="background-image:url(https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/9034/2568020-4372935613-any%252.jpg)" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466639"></a>
</div>
<div id="residential"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code that needs to be fixed:

- You are binding the same event many times with the images ids, it will cost you less code and give best performance if you just give them a class and bind the event to it, or just bind the event to the container divs of images.
- And if you bind the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events directly to the images they will fire when the cursor goes outside of them to their container div, that's what happens when you add the margin.

**Solution:**

I think the best and cleanest approach is to bind the events with parent div of each image once using `.portfolioimages` class, it will fix your code problems.

This is how should be the code:

```
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find("img").animate({marginLeft: "20%"}, {duration: 250, queue: false});
});

$(".portfolioimages").mouseout(function() {
   $(this).find("img").animate({marginLeft: "0%"}, { duration: 250, queue: false});
});
```

**Demo:**

Here's a working snippet with your code optimsed.

```js
$(".portfolioimages").mouseover(function() {
  $(this).find("img").animate({
    marginLeft: "20%"
  }, {
    duration: 250,
    queue: false
  });
});

$(".portfolioimages").mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find("img").animate({
    marginLeft: "0%"
  }, {
    duration: 250,
    queue: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="commercialopacity"></div>
<p class="commercial">COMMERCIAL</p>
<div id="hideimage"></div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
  <img class="picture" id="commercialimage1" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 1-1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
  <img class="picture" id="commercialimage2" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 2-1.jpg" link="index.html">
</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">
  <img class="picture" id="commercialimage3" src="Project Images\\HarrisonHealthClinic\\Render 3-1.jpg">
</div>
<div id="residential"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This definitely definitely makes my jQuery code easier to read, however, this still does not work under the opaque screen I have over the images. Anything I could do about that?